# how to change the structure of the output

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is the start of the object. I should be able to get the elements of `celldata.values`.

```js
    var generatedObj1 = {
      "agg": "Glossar",
      "ifa": null,
      "ifv": null,
      "ird": null,
      "afv": null,
      "ard": null,
      "metaData": {
        "cellMetaDataList": [{
          "cell": "glossar", // <-- cell type 
          "cmv": null,
          "crd": null,
          "logicalData": {
            "body": [{
                "id": "f5d", // <-- body id 1
                "name": "name", // <-- attribute name 1
                "minLength": 3,
                "maxLength": 100,
                "minValue": null,
                "maxValue": null,
                "wertebereich": "ALPHANUMERISCH",
                "validationCode": "",
                "exampleValues": ["Langer Name", "Kurzer Name", "Kein Name"]
              },
              {
                "id": "42", // <-- body id 2
                "name": "kurzname", // <-- attribute name 2
                "minLength": 3,
                "maxLength": 20,
                "minValue": null,
                "maxValue": null,
                "wertebereich": "ALPHANUMERISCH",
                "validationCode": "",
                "exampleValues": ["long_desc", "short_desc", "no_desc"]
              },
              {
                "id": "9d", // <-- body id 3
                "name": "eindeutig", // <-- attribute name 3
                "minLength": 1,
                "maxLength": 1,
                "minValue": null,
                "maxValue": null,
                "wertebereich": "WAHRHEITSWERT",
                "validationCode": "",
                "exampleValues": [true, false]
              }
            ]
          }
        }]
      },
      "data": {
        "cellData": [{ // row 1 from res1
            "cell": "glossar", // <-- cell type 
            "id": "5b", // <- UUID v4 (generated by the function)
            "cmv": null,
            "crd": null,
            "caption": {
              "pers": "string",
              "custNr": "string",
              "fnam": "string",
              "snam": "string",
              "sysId": "string"
            },
            "values": [{
                "name": "name", // <-- attribute name 1
                "value": "Langer Name",
                "bodyRefId": "5d" // <-- body id 1
              },
              {
                "name": "kurzname", // <-- attribute name 2
                "value": "no_desc",
                "bodyRefId": "42" // <-- body id 2
              },
              {
                "name": "eindeutig", // <-- attribute name 3
                "value": false,
                "bodyRefId": "9d" // <-- body id 3
              }
            ]
          },
          { // row 2 from res1
            "cell": "glossar", // <-- cell type 
            "id": "5c", // <- UUID v4 (generated by the function)
            "cmv": null,
            "crd": null,
            "caption": {
              "pers": "string",
              "custNr": "string",
              "fnam": "string",
              "snam": "string",
              "sysId": "string"
            },
            "values": [{
                "name": "name", // <-- attribute name 1
                "value": "Kein Name",
                "bodyRefId": "5d" // <-- body id 1
              },
              {
                "name": "kurzname", // <-- attribute name 2
                "value": "short_desc",
                "bodyRefId": "42" // <-- body id 2
              },
              {
                "name": "eindeutig", // <-- attribute name 3
                "value": true,
                "bodyRefId": "9d" // <-- body id 3
              }
            ]
          },
          { // row 3 from res1
            "cell": "glossar", // <-- cell type 
            "id": "5d", // <- UUID v4 (generated by the function)
            "cmv": null,
            "crd": null,
            "caption": {
              "pers": "string",
              "custNr": "string",
              "fnam": "string",
              "snam": "string",
              "sysId": "string"
            },
            "values": [{
                "name": "name", // <-- attribute name 1
                "value": "Kurzer Name",
                "bodyRefId": "5d" // <-- body id 1
              },
              {
                "name": "kurzname", // <-- attribute name 2
                "value": "short_desc",
                "bodyRefId": "42" // <-- body id 2
              },
              {
                "name": "eindeutig", // <-- attribute name 3
                "value": true,
                "bodyRefId": "9d" // <-- body id 3
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

> Blockquote

the returned array should be converted to match the metadata.
Each entry in the array describes an object in the result object.
and should be able to change implement the requirement in the function below.

```js
     function add(input1) {
        let exampleValues1 = input1.metaData.cellMetaDataList[0].logicalData.body.map(({
          exampleValues
        }) => exampleValues);

        return comb(exampleValues1,20);
      }
```

the combination function .

```
 function comb(args,output) {
var combination = [], max = args.length-1;
function helper(arr, i) {
    for (var j=0, l=args[i].length; j<l; j++) {
        var a = arr.slice(0); // clone arr
        a.push(args[i][j]);
        if (i==max)
            combination.push(a);
        else
            helper(a, i+1);
    }
}
helper([], 0);
while(combination.length < output){
combination = combination.concat(combination)}
return combination.sort(function() {
  return .5 - Math.random();
}).slice(0,output); }
 console.log(add(generatedObj1));
```

Sample result:

```
 [["Langer Name", "no_desc", false],
   ["Kein Name", "short_desc", true]
   ["Kurzer Name", "short_desc", true]
     ];
```

the returned array should be converted to match the metadata.
Each entry in the array describes an object in the result object.

You can still just call the add function and get your input with it
The input does not change at all we are just changing the output... (that's why the ticket is named adaptation of the output structure)

For every string artay within the output of the comb function the add function should create one object within the cellData element. It should have cell type, an id, a null cmv and crd value, as well es the caption object
Most importantly it should have an values array having an object withe the name of the attribute (from body.name) the value (from the array comb returned) and a bodyRefId (from body.id)

How can I implement this in my function `add()`?

Comment: `map` returns an array, and what is the `comb()` function returning? Also you are trying to destructure `exampleValues` as an object when it is an array.

Comment: comb is another function which is used to combine the array i.e. the example values . yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object from an array by filling the fields of the object using the Square brackets notation. The method would look like this:

```
function mapArrayToObject(cellDataValues) {
    const obj = {};
    cellDataValues.forEach(element => {
        const fieldName = element[0];
        const fieldValue = element[2];
        obj[fieldName] = fieldValue;
    });
    return obj;
}
```

### Update 09/17/2020 (The question was misunderstood)

After studying your question carefully I guess that your objective is the next one: After the execution of the add function what you want to get is an object with some fields (`id`, `cell`, `caption`...) and a `values` field that contains the values computed by the `comb` function, but parsed into objects that contains information about the `body`.

In order to achieve it I purpose a solution divided in 3 steps inside the `add` function:

1. Create an object with all the fields that are not related to the values computed by the `comb` function.
2. Execute the `comb` function.
3. Iterate through the values obtained, using the object created at *step one* as a template (cloning it) and use the index of the value you are iterating through to know which `body` you are pointing to in order to obtain the `name` and `bodyRefId` for each value.

The implementation would be:

```
function add(input1) {

    // FIRST STEP: Creating the template object
    const metaData = input1.metaData.cellMetaDataList[0];
    const bodies = metaData.logicalData.body;
    let emptyObj = {
        id: "ID GENERATED BY THE FUNCTION",
        cell: metaData.cell,
        cmv: null,
        crd: null,
        caption: {
            "pers": "string",
            "custNr": "string",
            "fnam": "string",
            "snam": "string",
            "sysId": "string"
        }
    };

    // SECOND STEP: Calling to the comb function
    let exampleValues1 = bodies.map(({ exampleValues }) => exampleValues);
    const valuesArr =  comb(exampleValues1,20);

    // THIRD STEP: Parsing (Tricky part)
    // Iterating through each collection of values -> [], [], []
    const valuesObj = valuesArr.map(arr => {

        // Cloning the template object
        const obj = { ...emptyObj };

        // Iterating through each value -> 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'
        const valuesArr = arr.map((value, index) => {
            // Using the index in order to know the body.
            // For example, when index is 0 we know that we can get the name from bodies[0]
            return {
                name: bodies[index].name,
                value: value,
                bodyRefId: bodies[index].id
            }
        })

        // Assigning the parsed values to the cloned template object
        obj.values = valuesArr;

        // Returning the object as we are using the map function
        return obj;
    });

    // Now, valuesObj should have the expected structure
    return valuesObj;
}
```

Comment: This change might be implemented as part of  add function, as here the combined array and the original object are available.but how can i implement this in my add function ?

Comment: and i dont want to use any library .

Comment: Okey I think this update will solve your problem :)